# Is typecasting the message when using SendMessageW() always necessary?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is typecasting the message when using `SendMessageW()` always necessary, or am I using a "non-ideal" type for my message?  If it is not always necessary, what is the type that I would use that would not require it to be cast?

```
std::wstring LBstring;
...
SendMessageW(hWndList1, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)LBstring.c_str());
```

Further, generally, is typecasting never necessary, minimally necessary, or often necessary?  When I worked with ANSI C back in the 90s, I was under the impression (maybe falsely) that typecasting was just forcing something to be something it wasn't, and so was undesirable.

Comment: The casting of arguments to WinAPI calls is very often necessary, especially for the `lParam` argument to message functions. This is because those message often use a pointer for that parameter and the actual `LPARAM` type is integral.

Comment: In C++, some form of cast (either 'C-Style' or `reinterpret_cast`) is absolutely required for those `lParam` arguments. In C, the implicit conversion rules are a bit less stringent but you still need them in many cases.

Comment: Okay.  So I should expect to always have to cast the message in `SendMessage()` as `(LPARAM)`?  I figured I must be doing something wrong since I couldn't get it to work without casting it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-listbox_addstring

Comment: To anyone that follows the link above: Make sure to click the *"Feedback"* link, select *"No"* to the question whether the page was helpful, and optionally leave a note that the macro documentation (like **EVERY OTHER MACRO DOCUMENTATION**) is wrong. It expands to a value of type `int`, not `void`. We've been asking for years to have this crap fixed, that was broken for no reason. Please make sure to have your voice heard, if it matters to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `SendMessage()` directly, then yes, the casting is necessary, since it only accepts integer values as parameters, not pointers.  But the integers are large enough to hold pointer values, in cases where messages operate on pointers, like `LB_ADDSTRING` does.

In any case, for this particular situation, you can avoid the casting by using the [`ListBox_AddString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-listbox_addstring) macro instead:

```
...
#include <windowsx.h>

std::wstring LBstring;
...
ListBox_AddString(hWndList1, LBstring.c_str());
```

It handles the casting for you:

```
#define ListBox_AddString(hwndCtl, lpsz)            ((int)(DWORD)SNDMSG((hwndCtl), LB_ADDSTRING, 0L, (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)(lpsz)))
```

Many Win32 UI controls have similar wrapper macros defined for their respective messages.

Comment: Understood on the wrapper macro. Any comment on the value of using the macro versus SendMessageW() other than not having to explicitly cast?

Comment: @pwn01 using the macros will make the code cleaner and easier to read/maintain. That is why they exist in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As [Adrian Mole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10871073/adrian-mole) noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74826743/is-typecasting-the-message-when-using-sendmessagew-always-necessary/74827266#comment132055993_74826743):

> The casting of arguments to WinAPI calls is very often necessary, especially for the `lParam` argument to message functions. This is because those messages often use a pointer for that parameter and the actual `LPARAM` type is integral.

> In C++, some form of cast (either 'C-Style' or reinterpret_cast) is absolutely required for those `lParam` arguments. In C, the implicit conversion rules are a bit less stringent but you still need them in many cases.